# Simulations of polymer chain with metropolis

Tags: python-3.x, polymer, montecarlo

I'm trying to simulate a polymer chain, but in the function total_energy the error " The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()" comes. It seems to me that I'm making a mistake in defining the distinction between the arrays and lists. Could someone point the issue?

```py
def gen_chain(N, R):
    x = np.linspace(0, (N - 1) * R * 0.8, num=N)
    y = np.zeros(N)
    z = np.zeros(N)
    return np.column_stack((x, y, z))

def lj(rij): # Lennard-Jones potential
    lje = 4.0 * epsilon* (sigma**12/rij**12 - sigma**6/r**6)

    return lje

def fene(rij):

    return (-0.5 * K * R0**2 * np.log(1 - ((rij - r0) / R)**2))

def total_energy(coord):
    # Non-bonded
    e_nb = 0
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(i-1):
            ri = coord[i]
            rj = coord[j]
            rij = ri - rj
            if (rij < rcutoff): # HERE THE ERROR COMES
                e_nb += lj(rij)

    e_bond = 0
    for i in range(1, N):
        ri = coord[i]
        rj = coord[i-1]
        rij = ri - rj
        e_bond += fene(rij)
    return e_nb + e_bond

def move(coord):
    trial = np.ndarray.copy(coord)
    for i in range(N):
        delta = (2.0 * np.random.rand(3) - 1) * max_delta
        trial[i] += delta
    return trial

def accept(delta_e):
    beta = 1.0 / T
    if delta_e <= 0.0:
        return True
    random_number = np.random.rand(1)
    p_acc = np.exp(-beta * delta_e)
    if random_number < p_acc:
        return True
    return False

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # FENE parameters
    K = 40
    R0 = 0.3
    r0 = 0.7

    # LJ parameters
    sigma = r0 / 2**1 / 6  # 0.572
    epsilon = 1.0

    # MC parameters
    N = 50  # number of particles
    rcutoff = (2.5 * sigma)**2
    max_delta = 0.01
    n_steps = 10000
    T = 0.5

    coord = gen_chain(N, R0)
    energy_current = total_energy(coord)

    traj = open('traj_T_05.xyz', 'w')

    for step in range(n_steps):
        if step % 1000 == 0:
            traj.write(str(N) + '\n\n')
            for i in range(N):
                traj.write("C %10.5f %10.5f %10.5f\n" % (coord[i][0], coord[i][1], coord[i][2]))
            print(step, energy_current)
        coord_trial = move(coord)
        energy_trial = total_energy(coord_trial)
        delta_e = energy_trial - energy_current
        if accept(delta_e):
            coord = coord_trial
            energy_current = energy_trial

    traj.close()
```

Comment: I posted the rest of the code below. If I use rij2(np.dot(ri, rj)) then code works, but I do not want the square.

Comment: I edit the code. I used only parts of the code which are useful.

Comment: You probably want to also have a "import numpy as np" line at the very top.

Answer (score 0):

The specific error you are getting is due to `rij` being an array, whereas `rcutoff` is a number. You can either compute the length of `rij` and compare it with the cutoff:

```
if np.sqrt(np.dot(rij, rij)) < rcutoff:
```

or use define `rcutoff_sqr = rcutoff**2` and use it to save some square-root calculations:

```
if np.dot(rij, rij) < rcutoff_sqr:
```

Note that your code won't quite work after that, as there are more errors you'll have to fix (undefined variables, divide by zero and probably more).